# jQuery.validate.js equalTo refuses to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to validate that my one password equals the other. The system keeps flagging the passwords not equal error.

Let me post my code:

```
<div class="fieldWrapper">
              <label for="password" id="id_password">Password: </label>
              <input id="id_password" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" maxlength="128" class="valid">
           </div>

<div class="fieldWrapper">
              <label for="password_verification">Confirm:</label>
              <input id="id_password_verification" type="password" placeholder="Confirm" name="password_verification" maxlength="128">
           </div>

$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#signup-form").validate({
    rules: {
        password: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },

        password_verification: {
            required : true,
            equalTo: "#id_password"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        password: {
            required: "Please provide a password",
            minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
        },

        password_verification: {
            required: "Please enter your password again",
            equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
        },
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
  });
});
```

Does anyone have any clue where I am going wrong here?  Note that my form has the id signup-form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have dupplicate `id` in your HTML:

`<label for="password" id="id_password">Password: </label>`

remove `id` from the `label`.